# Python Selenium- Unable to click UI element having HTML tag i class

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, ui-automation, browser-automation

All the UI elements having the HTML tag "`i class`" are not getting clicked

Below is the HTML of the element i am trying to click on:

```
<button class="btn btn-icon btn-transparent  undefined" eventkey="1"><i class="fa fa-bolt hx-primary inline-actions-overview" title="Test this"></i></button>
```

I have tried various below methods with css and xpaths but nothing seems to work:

```
1.) self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '.fa-bolt').click()
2.) ActionChains(self.driver.get_driver()).move_to_element(element).send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
3.) ActionChains(self.driver.get_driver()).move_to_element(element).double_click(element).perform()
4.) self.driver.execute_script("arguments[0].click();", element)
```

Any help appreciated !!

**NOTE: The element I need to click on is from the below HTML:**

```
<i class="fa fa-bolt hx-primary inline-actions-overview" title="Test this"></i>
```

Comment: share the more part of html code for respective element. if URL is public then share it.

Comment: Try i.fa.fa-bolt.hx-primary.inline-actions-overview and post any error messages. I'm not sure if there's a space between primary and inline.

Comment: Have updated the complete HTML of the element